# %post scriptlet failed.. Where is this scriptlet located?

Tags: linux, rpm, scriptlet

I have an error:

```
%post(blabla.i386) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
```

Where is located this scriptlet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's in the RPM. You can view it by using the `-q` option:

```
 rpm -q --scripts blabla
```

Answer (score 1):

you can view script by using `-qp --scripts` option on `blabla.rpm` file

```
rpm -qp --scripts blabla.rpm
```